# Double integral:$\iint_{x+y\leq1, \,x\geq0, \, y\geq0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x-y}}\, dxdy$

Tags: calculus

I have this double integral

$$\iint\limits_{\substack{x+y\leq1 \\x\geq0\\ y\geq0}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x-y}}\,dxdy$$
I think I need to replace variables but I don’t know how to replace.

Comment: No, just use Fubini

Comment: Welcome to the MSE! It would be nice if you include your work or context in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1-x}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{1-x-y}}}\,\mathrm{d}x} =\int_{0}^{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{4}{3}$$